# Bug in react-native-vector-icons, Icons is in japanese

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have a react-native app.

I have an app but when i use icons(react-native-vector-icons) the icon show in japanese, example:

The icon that i want to use is "add"

[Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6NmJ.png)

But when i show the icon on my app that show like this:

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kLhT.png)

The code of this app is:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwxud.png)

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
                <Icon name="add" color="#000" size={22} />
              </Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
});
```

React-native Doctor:

```
 Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ yarn

Android
 ✖ JDK
   - Version found: 1.8.0_265
   - Version supported: >= 8
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   2
Warnings: 0

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got same issue.Follow this instruction :
Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the following:
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

And rebuild.